# Windows 10 1903 - LongPathAware not working?

Tags: winapi, filesystems

Below is the manifest I use.  It works fine for the OS version information, but on my system it doesn't enable long path support.  I can take my long path *"x:\whatever\whatever\etc"* that fails with path not found in `CreateFile()` (Unicode build) and just prepend `\\?\` and works fine.    The DWORD registry value `LongPathsEnabled` is set to `1` at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` and have rebooted the system.

What am I doing wrong.  I would assume it's in the manifest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
  <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
      <application> 
        <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista --> 
          <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
        <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 --> 
          <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/> 
        <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 8 --> 
          <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
    <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
          <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
    <!-- Windows 10 -->
          <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
      </application> 
    </compatibility>
    <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
      <windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="https://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
        <ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>
      </windowsSettings>
    </application>  
  </assembly>
```

Comment: Can you amend your question with sample code of how you are invoking CreateFile?

Comment: Did you enable the *"Enable Win32 long paths"* group policy as well?

Comment: I didn't enable the group policy since the MS docs say you can optionally use that to control the registry value, instead if set it myself. `This registry key can also be controlled via Group Policy at Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > Enable NTFS long paths.`

Comment: The CreateFile looks like:  `h=CreateFile(filename, access, share, NULL, action, flags, NULL);`

Comment: I enabled the group policy at `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > Enable NTFS long paths` rebooted and it made no difference.   Still won't work unless I put the \\?\ in front of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following XML:

```
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
      <ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

Comment: I have repro it and the xml above works for me, I will confirm with the relevant engineer, whether this is a document issue or the issue of usage, or sth others.

Comment: Isn't that what I already have?  Except using https instead of http ?  Do I have it in correct place mixed with the other?

Comment: Hi, @df234987 We have confirmed this issue("https" and "http"), and Microsoft Engineers are working on it.

Comment: @riQQ, check the following documents, it has been update to "http":[Enable Long Paths in Windows 10, Version 1607, and Later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later) and [longPathAware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests#longpathaware)

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem was the manifest contents.   The manifest that works is:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
      <windowsSettings>
        <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
      </windowsSettings>
    </application>
```

I just replaced that section in my original manifest so it can be combined in the same file.    Don't ask me why so much wrong information out there, even at MS site.  Speaking of that site, I find so many useful links are now dead, why would MS just leave the old KB stuff there?

Comment: This is actually the same as my answer. Currently, we are waiting for the reply from relevant internal personnel.

Comment: It doesn't look like it, you have the ws2: and xmlns:ws2= items like I originally had.   I see at one point you had it but then changed it ?  but maybe it was just the https vs http